# Rails 2 paper clip version 2.3.3 ruby 1.9.2 storing image name with single quote and double quote change original name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, paperclip

I am working with rails 2 application and using paperclip plugin with version 2.3.3.

While storing image  with name **abc'".jpg** it store as **".jpg** in database .

Help me to store with original file name OR if atleast rename the file by abc.jpg and remove the wildcard characters

Answer (score 0):

Before you save the record add the following constraint:

```
 @model_name.image_file_name = @model_name.image_file_name.gsub(/['"]/,"")
```

Replace `@model_name` with the instance variable you are saving.

Since, you haven't shared the relevant code along with model details. I will share my example that I have tested in my application:

For example:

For a model `Pin` with Paperclip attachment attribute named `image`. Write the PinsController `create` and `update` actions as below:

```
  def create
    @pin = Pin.new(params[:pin])
    @pin.image_file_name = @pin.image_file_name.gsub(/['"]/,"")       
    @pin.save
    .....
    .....
  end

  def update
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    @pin.image_file_name = @pin.image_file_name.gsub(/['"]/,"")       
    @pin.update_attributes(..)
    .....
    .....
  end
```

`.gsub(/['"]/,"")` will remove the unwanted `'` and `"` from the uploaded filename. If you have any other wild cards apart from `'` and `"` then add it in the gsub call.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. but I am getting ".jpg in image_file_name object in controller as if you get in @pin.image_file_name so there is not question of using gsub on that.

Comment: I think it is rails 2.3 truncation issue that truncated values at the point of the quote.

Comment: That means there are two issues: You have a file called abc'".jpg as mentioned in the question which will become `abc.jpg` by using my given answer. BUT, if you have `".jpg` then above solution will give you filename as `.jpg`. What did you try? Did you even try my answer? Let me know your findings.

Comment: I am not getting the right file name in params in controller so there is no reason to apply your logic of gsub on the image file name in params.
I think issue is in rails 2 in post request if text field or params has single quote then it removes the character before this quotes.
so basically I am getting the wrong file name in controller. This is my findings.